# Export Errors while building next.js project (non-react exports error and prerendering error)

Tags: javascript, next.js

Everything works fine when I run the site locally using yarn dev.

And the Homepage looks like this -

[image]

The directory structure looks something like this -

[image]

Notice that the components folder is inside pages folder.

But when I try to build this using yarn build, I get following error:

[image]
image continued below:
[image]

So I tried putting the whole components folder outside the pages folder, which makes the build run successfully but the UI goes nuts:

The updated project dir:

[image]

The UI after moving components outside pages folder.

[image]

Why does this happen, when all the imports are updated accordingly.
Is there a way around it, or re-writing the whole codebase is my only option.

**NOTE:** I tried moving only the files/dirs mentioned in the build error (like nftPreview, contentCard etc) but same thing happens. So I thought it'll be better to put the whole component folder outside pages folder for future's sake.

Here's the github link of the project - https://github.com/xylanreeves/bitverse

Comment: Are the CSS imports updated?

Comment: wdym?  am using tailwind-css.

Comment: I've added github link of the project, could you pls check

Comment: @youdateme hey thanks for the help, I needed to update my Content Configuration inside tailwind.config.js, It's working fine now 